# I want to Split Datatable rows based on number

Tags: c#

I have datatable and i want to split the number of rows based on foreach 12 row
for example if the number of rows is 61 : that's mean 
61 / 12 = 6 Tables 
5 tables with 12 rows and the table number 6 have 3 rows 
C#
Thanks alot

Comment: you do know that 61 rows will not overwhelm your DB, right?

Comment: please Take some time to describe your question properly

Comment: And I want a beer, please.

Comment: Tim answer is correct but don't forget to add "System.Linq" namespace in your code behind

Comment: By the way, there is only one remaing row not three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use following LINQ query:

```
DataTable[] splittedtables = tbl.AsEnumerable()
    .Select((row, index) => new { row, index })
    .GroupBy(x => x.index / 12)  // integer division, the fractional part is truncated
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.row).CopyToDataTable())
    .ToArray();
```

The array contains 6 tables, 5 with 12 rows, the last one has the remaining row.

Checked with this sample-data:

```
DataTable  tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("Column");
for(int i=0; i < 61; i++)
    tbl.Rows.Add(i.ToString());
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;`.